# PostgreSQL 9.3 idle in transaction

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, sqltransaction

In our product sometimes there is a situation when a database is locked with an `idle in transaction` connection.

I am using postgresql-9.3(9.4), java connection via jdbc driver.
All connections are set to be autocommit.

The problem can only be solved by using `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(PID)`. I don't like such a decision, but that or rebooting the service are the only things that work.

So there is a question how to solve such a problem when I don't manipulate transactions manually. All connections to Postgres are local, so i don't think that's a network problem.

**Update**
All right no doubt - there is an application bug.

Imagine, that we have got a query:

```
try(PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement("update table1 set some_field=1 where id=2")){
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

So a simple query for local connection. Connection is active. Autocommit is true. What issue should happen for such connection to be `idle in transaction`?

**Update** 
Thanks anyone for attention. The problem was solved by changing jdbc-driver to the latest version.

Comment: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and 9.4 will be unsupported in a few months. You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: There should be a problem cause government restrictions for nowadays to upgrade to higher version

Comment: That's ridiculous (I know it's not your fault) Those government restrictions should prohibit the use of outdated software that doesn't receive any security fixes anymore (in Germany we have a law for certain infrastructures that prohibits that). Upgrading from 9.3.25 to 11.5 [gives you 1851 bugfixes](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.3.25&to=11.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks anyone for attention. The problem was solved by changing jdbc-driver to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions that remain in status `idle in transaction` for a long time are an application bug, but you are probably aware of that.

One stop-gap “solution” to the problem is to set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` to a non-zero value. This parameter is available from 9.6 on, which gives you one more excellent reason to upgrade to the latest version soon.